# How to use if statement - loops

Tags: loops, prolog

i am trying to understand how to use if statement or loops in prolog but i can't get it,cause there are a bunch of different situations.Example in java if you want to say something you could say easily `if(x>=4) { } else if { }` .If you want to do something do-while loop until `(x>4)`.In prolog,there are many issues.Let me clear it up.I see an exercise telling we have 1 list1 with numbers and we have list2, i mean `doubles(List1,List2)`.What i should do is i must create a new list2 in which all of the numbers of List1 must be up to 10,but it should be appear twice each of those numbers on the list2. 
Explanation what needs to clear it more, in list1 there is a number lets say 14 ,is bigger than 10 so in list2 it must be 14,14.How can you create if statement,or loops on list like those for example.Yes i have read enough but this language is weird at least to me.I have learn for example if statement but i can't use it on this case.I have searched here but nothing suite at it.Please,if you could clear it up with if statements and loops in prolog by giving good explanation.It will helpful to create "similar" as java if statement or loops to get more understandable to someone who is begginer in prolog .Cause i stuck when i go solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just going to comment, but the comments were getting long!

The biggest problem most Prolog beginners have is they think in terms of "How do I do X in Prolog like I do X in this other language". Many times this fails because Prolog isn't at all like other languages. Yes, you can force it, but then eventually end up with a very poorly written Prolog program. Instead, you need to think about the original problem and recast it in terms of how Prolog works. In Prolog, you declare facts and rules that describe logical and arithmetic relationships (declarative), not functions that direct the computer what to do using sequences of steps (imperative). This is not an "issue" with Prolog. The issue is that the beginner doesn't understand Prolog.

Let's start to describe your problem in Prolog terms. You need a rule that describes the relationship between the lists in which the second list duplicates elements of the first that are greater than 10. Let's call the relation `dup_greater_than_10`.

The base case is simple: the empty list `[]` is the "dup greater than 10" of the empty list:

```
dup_greater_than_10([], []).
```

Now you need to handle each element in the non-empty list. A list in Prolog can be written as a head and tail (rest of list): `[X|Xs]` is a list whose first element is `X` and the "rest of the list" (the tail) is the list `Xs`.

Let's write a rule for the case where `X` is not greater than 10. In this case, the 2nd argument should have the same head as the 1st argument:

```
dup_greater_than_10([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
    X =< 10,
    dup_greater_than_10(Xs, Ys).
```

This rule says that `[X|Ys]` is the "dup greater than 10" version of list `[X|Xs]` if `X =< 10` *and* the list `Ys` is the "dup greater than 10" of the list `Xs`.

Now you need a rule for the case `X > 10`. I'll describe it and leave the writing of the simple Prolog to you:

> `[X,X|Ys]` is the "dup greater than 10" of `[X|Xs]` *if* `X > 10` and the list `Ys` is the "dup greater than 10" of the list `Xs`.

See how simple it is to express the duplication of `X` in the head of a list? In Prolog, you can write a list: `[X1, X2, ..., Xn|T]` which is a list that starts with initial elements `X1`, `X2`, ..., `Xn` and tail `T`.

So you see, you're asking the wrong question when you ask "How do I do `if` statements and `loops` in Prolog?". That's like asking, "How do I pound in a nail with this wrench?" It can be done, but it's inefficient and it ain't pretty. The right question is: "How do I solve this kind of problem in Prolog?"